# Scraping and sorting dates from a website using Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to sort dates from some results in a website. I found dates between tags `<span class="f"`. Unfortunately, I cannot extract this kind of information using the code below. I would like to ask you what it is wrong in the code and how I can extract dates and sorting them in ascending/descending order.

What I already did is to collect the information (first 20 results) from the website into an array. The array urls[] is collecting information (sentences) published in different periods (in terms of months, days, minutes...). You could think of posts on Facebook or results in Google.

```
urls=[]
for url in search(' " life " ', stop=20):
    urls.append(url) # this creates a list of results (sentences. For each of them I would like to report the date when it was published)

soup = BeautifulSoup(url)

for url in urls:
    url = soup.find_all('span', {'class':'f'})

            # <span class="f">2 days ago - </span>

    print(url)
```

I should expect results such as, for example,

```
"Yesterday I went out with my friends"     2 days ago    the oldest result 
"I played basketball for several years"   20 hours ago  ....
.... 19 hours ago  ....
.... 5 hours ago   ....

...
```

for each sentence. So I should have two arrays, one for sentences and one for their date respectively, in order to plot them.

The raw data is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeyQb.png)

Could you please help me giving suggestions on how to do that?
Thanks

Comment: Looks like already in oldest to newest order? Can you share url?

Comment: Please give an example of the actual contents of `url`. Is it like `<span class="f">2 days ago - sentence </span>`?

Comment: I don't mean the desired output, I mean the raw data that you're getting from `find_all()`.

Comment: I just added a picture to show the raw data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires several steps:

- first, extract only the duration from each URL by removing the `span` tags. You can do this with `replace()`, `split()` or you could use regular expressions.
- sort the durations into different categories (days, hours, etc)
- in each category, sort the durations in reverse order (eg. 2 hours ago should come before 1 hour ago)
- finally, join the categories (days, hours etc.) into a single string in the correct order (days should come before hours).

Here's a working implementation. Note that you can extend it to also support minutes, months etc.

```
elements = [
'<span class="f">21 hours ago - </span>',
'<span class="f">20 hours ago - </span>',
'<span class="f">2 days ago - </span>',
'<span class="f">1 day ago - </span>']

# extract the durations (eg. 21 hours ago) and store them in times list
times = [elem.replace('<span class="f">','').replace(' - </span>','') for elem in elements]

# categorize the times into days and hours
days = [time for time in times if "day" in time]
hours = [time for time in times if "hour" in time]

# sort each category in reverse order
days.sort(reverse=True)
hours.sort(reverse=True)

# join categories into a string, such that each time is on a new line
output = '\n'.join(days) + '\n' + '\n'.join(hours)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
2 days ago
1 day ago
21 hours ago
20 hours ago
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@glhr/55552138

Another more scalable approach is to use a dictionary to convert every duration into a certain number of minutes, store those numeric durations into a separate list, and sort the original list of strings based on the numeric list:

```
elements = [
'<span class="f">21 hours ago - </span>',
'<span class="f">20 hours ago - </span>',
'<span class="f">2 days ago - </span>',
'<span class="f">1 day ago - </span>']

# extract the durations (eg. 21 hours ago) and store them in times list
times = [elem.replace('<span class="f">','').replace(' - </span>','') for elem in elements]

minutes_per_duration = {"hours": 60, "hour": 60, "minute": 1, "minutes": 1, "day": 1440, "days": 1440}

duration_values = []

for time in times:
    duration = time.split(" ")[1] # eg. hours
    number = int(time.split(" ")[0]) # eg. 21
    minutes = minutes_per_duration[duration] # eg. 60 (for hours)
    total = minutes * number # 21 * 60 = 1260
    duration_values.append(total)

# sort times based on calculated duration values
output = '\n'.join([times for duration_values, times in sorted(zip(duration_values, times),reverse=True)])

print(output)
```

Output:

```
2 days ago
1 day ago
21 hours ago
20 hours ago
```

---

In your code, you can implement it like this:

```
def durationSpansToSortedList(elements):
    # extract the durations (eg. 21 hours ago) and store them in times list
    times = [elem.replace('<span class="f">','').replace(' - </span>','') for elem in elements]

    minutes_per_duration = {"hours": 60, "hour": 60, "minute": 1, "minutes": 1, "day": 1440, "days": 1440}

    duration_values = []

    for time in times:
            duration = time.split(" ")[1] # eg. hours
            number = int(time.split(" ")[0]) # eg. 21
            minutes = minutes_per_duration[duration] # eg. 60 (for hours)
            total = minutes * number # 21 * 60 = 1260
            duration_values.append(total)

    # sort times based on calculated duration values
    # return times as list
    return [[times for duration_values, times in sorted(zip(duration_values, times),reverse=True)], duration_values]

urls=[]
for url in search(' " life " ', stop=20):
    urls.append(url) # this creates a list of results (sentences. For each of them I would like to report the date when it was published)

spanElements = []
sentenceElements = []

for url in urls:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "html.parser")
        spanElements.append(str(soup.find_all('span', {'class':'f'})[0]))
        sentenceElements.append(url)

sortedDurations, duration_values = durationSpansToSortedList(spanElements)
print("Sorted durations:", sortedDurations,"\n")

sortedSentences = [sentenceElements for duration_values, sentenceElements in sorted(zip(duration_values, sentenceElements), reverse=True)]
print("Sorted sentences:", sortedSentences)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191381/discussion-on-answer-by-glhr-scraping-and-sorting-dates-from-a-website-using-pyt).